# Auto-wrap typed text

Tags: far-manager

### 1. Briefly

I can't find how Far Manager can auto-wrap to new line long commands that I type.

---

### 2. Settings

For example, I wrote command in terminal:

```
sfk replace Sasha-Black-description.html -pat "_css/Sasha-Black_../css/Sasha-Black/_" -yes
```

---

### 3. Expected behavior

If I wrote this command in Clink or PowerShell mode of ConEmu, words from my command auto-wrap to new line, example:

[image: PowerShell]

---

### 4. Actual behavior

If I wrote my long commands in Far mode of ConEmu, words from my command don't auto-wrap to new line, example:

[image: Far]

I reproduce the problem in Far Manager without ConEmu.

---

### 5. Not helped

1. I have AutoWrap plugin in Far by default → I press <kbd>F11</kbd> → I don't find, [**how I can set AutoWrap plugin**](http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?p=112348#p112348).

[image: AutoWrap]

2. I install [**ESC plugin**](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?l=ru&pid=364) → in `Cfg/esc_abstract.xml` file I wrote `<margin autowrap="on" wrap="80" justify="on"/>` → I restart Far Manager → no effect.

---

### 6. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Far:**
3.0 (build 4900) x64

Comment: For reference: As you already know by now ( https://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?t=10722 ), it's not possible to wrap the command line. The Autowrap plugin works only in the editor and it will auto-wrap when you type, but not existing long lines.